# How to get Max Id from database when database table is empty?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-5

I have table called 'GRNHDReturn' in my database. I want to get the Max ReturnId from the table when table is empty. How can I do this?

GRNHDReturn Database
[image: GRNHDReturn Database]

```
public string getMax()
{
    GRNHDReturn grh = new GRNHDReturn();
    int max = 0;  
    if ((context.GRNHDReturns.Max(p => p.ReturnId) == 0))
    {
        max = 1;
        calculatemax = "RN" + max.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        max = context.GRNHDReturns.Max(p => p.ReturnId);
        int nextmax = max + 1;
        calculatemax = "RN" + nextmax.ToString();
    }
    return calculatemax;
}
```

Comment: Try: SELECT ISNULL(MAX(RowID), 0) FROM Table ?

Comment: @A. Greensmith: `select coalesce(max(t.RowID), 0) from MyTable t` - SQL-92 compartible

Comment: I want to get the Id to the code shown in my question,not the sql query.

Comment: Does your ID column has identity enabled

Comment: Its a auto generate Id and its not nullable

Comment: When I run above code, it gives an exception like bellow,                                                                                                      
"The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."    
I need to get bellow condition true.
 "if ((context.GRNHDReturns.Max(p => p.ReturnId) == 0))"

Comment: Can you not get your C# application to run the SQL and report back the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string getMax()
{
   GRNHDReturn grh = new GRNHDReturn();
   int? max = (from o in context.GRNHDReturns
                  select (int?)o.ReturnId).Max();
   if (max == 0 || max == null)
   {
      max = 1;
      calculatemax = "RN" + max.ToString();
   }
   else
   {
      int? nextmax = max + 1;
      calculatemax = "RN" + nextmax.ToString();
   }
   return calculatemax;
}
```

You can try this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything you want by these lines of code:

```
int max = 0;  
max = context.GRNHDReturns.Select(p => p.ReturnId)
             .DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
int nextmax = max + 1;
calculatemax = "RN" + nextmax.ToString();
return calculatemax;
```

By `DefaultIfEmpty()` you tell EF to return `0` (the default for `int`) if there are no records.